# Warhammer 40k: Do 'decurion' style detachments comprised of multiple formations still count as one detachment for ITC purposes?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tournament

Say I have a Hunter Contingent (the Tau 'decurion' style detachment) comprised of Hunter Cadre and an Optmised Stealth Cadre, will this count as one detachment against the ITC tournament limit of three detachments? Will I be able to add a formation detachment with a Riptide Wing and an allied detachment with an Assassinorum Operative?

Comment: Unless you're planning to go to an ITC tournament VERY soon it'll likely be rendered moot in a couple of months when 8th edition drops...

Comment: I'm going to two ITC tournaments later this month.

Comment: In that case your best bet is probably to contact the tournament organizers. As that's less a question about 40k and more about a specific tournament (which uses modified rules) it's probably not the best fit for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more related to specific tournament restrictions than actual play of the game. Plus in a little over a month the new edition of the game will be out and the answer will become irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that at _some_ point specific tournament restrictions become inappropriate - e.g. "My local game store announced a three-detachment limit; does X count?" should be answered by your local game store, not us. However, when a tournament circuit is big enough and has well established rules, then 1) its rules _become_ a significant aspect of how the game is played in practice, and 2) the existence of its rules and history make it reasonable to expect that some expert on the internet (i.e. one of us) might know or be able to derive the answer.

Comment: ITC is used in most large tournaments in competitive 40k (adepticon, LVO, etc). I think that my question is appropriate because the ITC rules are a de facto standard for late tournaments and are nearly a second set of rules to the game. It is very different from asking about something specific for my local meta, ad aslum seems to have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Decurion Style” Detachments comprised of multiple sub-detachments **count as 1 detachment** towards the 3 detachment limit.

Source: [ITC 2017 FAQ and Format Guidelines](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16nmBS2KZglu9JaGttpX_9lOYhYO2PQM47N8HvrsAA60/edit#heading=h.lnmuelgpxubm)  (linked from [ITC2017 FAQ, Format and Scenarios](https://www.frontlinegaming.org/community/frontline-gamings-independent-tournament-circuit/itc-2015-season-40k-tournament-format/))

A new edition may render this answer obsolete, but until then, this is the official ITC position.  Including full text for posterity:

> An army may duplicate a single Detachment, one time.
>
> Example: A list
>   may include 2 CADs, but not 3 CADs. Or, a single CAD, and 2 Allied
>   Detachments. Or, 3 Formations, 2 of which are the same Formation, etc.
>
> This includes “Decurion Style” Meta-Detachments which are comprised of
>   multiple datasheets and Formations. They may only take a single
>   duplicate Formation, one time within the Meta-Detachment, although
>   they make take duplicate Data Slate units within the Detachment if
>   permitted to do so. Example: Necrons may take the Decurion with 2
>   Canoptek Harvest formations within it, but no other duplicate
>   formations.
>
> Note: “Decurion Style” Detachments comprised of multiple
>   sub-detachments count as 1 detachment towards the 3 detachment limit.